# Are FromUri and FromQuery the same?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm familiar with `FromBody` and `FromRoute`. They seem to be clear.

I've used `FromUri` to handle multi-valued parameters mapping to a list or a `string[]`.

`FromQuery` sounds similar, but is there any difference?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FromUri in ASP.NET CORE 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195001/fromuri-in-asp-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score 57):

`[FromQuery]` attribute handles query parameters, i.e. key-value pairs coming after "?" in URI.
`[FromRoute]` attribute handles route parameters coming before "?" in URI, i.e. path parameters.

For example, if you configured route `"orders/{id}"`, then "id" is your route parameter, and if some actual request is like `"orders/123?showHistory=true"`, then "showHistory" is your query parameter.

`[FromUri]` attribute in Web API works like `[FromQuery]` in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: Disagree with your definition of `FromRoute`. First of all the example you use afterwards does not fit in the definition you gave (there is no ? in orders/{id}). Second, the correct definition should be that `FromRoute` binds to route *parameters*, i.e., in oders/{id}, id is a route parameter, not a query string parameter, for example, since there is no query string in this resource path, so the only way to bind to id in your example is to use `FromRoute`. `FromQuery` would be of no help.

Comment: @Veverke the definition I give for `FromRoute` on the second line of my answer doesn't seem to contradict your definition.